# Using PhantomJs with Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, phantomjs

Currently trying to implement this [JonnyW php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) with CakePHP 2.0. The problem seems to be that Cake can not find the the files.

---

When I call it this way:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'JonnyW/PhantomJs/Client');
```

CakePHP gives the error:

```
Error: Class 'Client' not found
```

---

When I call it this way:

```
App::path('Vendor', 'JonnyW/PhantomJs/Client');
```

CakePHP gives this error:

```
Error: The application is trying to load a file from the JonnyW/PhantomJs/Client plugin

Error: Make sure your plugin JonnyW/PhantomJs/Client is in the app/Plugin directory and was loaded

CakePlugin::load('JonnyW/PhantomJs/Client');
```

So, I thought I would give it a shot and load it into the Plugin directory, but it still gives the same error.

Just wondering if anyone has any insight on PhantomJs working with CakePHP?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this ? I am trying to load the same vendor wit the same cake version. And getting the same error. nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `App::import`:

`App::import('Vendor', 'JonnyW', array('file' => 'JonnyW/PhantomJs/Client.php'));`

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files

Answer (score 0):

I am actively using CakePHP and PhantomJS + CasperJS with the method below. You can pass variable through shell with phantomjs args and return the terminal echoed answer through last parameter of php's exec() command. Have been using this method for a while no problem so far.

```
    putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
    exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any ../Lib/ExampleCrawler/example.js ' . $url . ' 2>&1', $result);
```